# Android takepicture failed at Android version 4.1.1 but succeed in version 4.0.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

I got the LogCat :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1061)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1006)
at com.cidtech.portraitcatch.service.MyService.takePic(MyService.java:168)
at com.cidtech.portraitcatch.service.MyService$1.onClick(MyService.java:78)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4088)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16984)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the curial code is below:

```
public void takePic(){
    home_takePic.setEnabled(false);
    camera = Camera.open();
    if(bitmapList == null){
        bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

        camera.takePicture(null, null, new MyPictureCallback());
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }

            saveBitmapToSdcard();

    releaseResource();
    home_takePic.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I also do this:

```
public void takePic(){
    home_takePic.setEnabled(false);
    camera = Camera.open();
    ***camera.startPreview();***
    if(bitmapList == null){
        bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

        camera.takePicture(null, null, new MyPictureCallback());
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }

    //      saveBitmapToSdcard();

    releaseResource();
    home_takePic.setEnabled(true);
}
```

but still get the same Exception

the method camera.takePicture have been performed in version 4.0.4 but faild in version 4.1.1, who can tell me how to solve it ,please help me ,thanks

Comment: does it fail everytime or just sometimes?

Comment: fail everytime in version 4.1.1 but succeed in version 4.0.1 why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be making a call to `startPreview()` before you attempt the call to `takePicture()`. Do this after you call `Camera.open()`.

[As per Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html):

> Important: Call `startPreview()` to start updating the preview surface.
>   **Preview must be started before you can take a picture.**

[startPreview documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startPreview%28%29)

Comment: Post your updated code with that call and the updated exception stack.

Comment: I think I have to try other ways, the privacy requirements mandating the use of Preview

Comment: Privacy requirements? Either way you need a manifest permission for the camera & a uses-hardware for the camera as well; there's no explicit permission or privacy issue with using `startPreview()`, and it's required to function correctly.

Comment: Additionally, you will need a valid `SurfaceView` to pass to `setPreviewDisplay()`; using a dummy (`null`) preview element won't work any longer.

Comment: What was the issue? If not my answer, please post your own answer for future visitors!

Comment: @bankel Please let us know how you got around the dreaded "takePicture failed" error!

Comment: @JoshuaWitter The takepicture action does not occure in the indepentent Application. Usually we take pickture by SurfaceView,which is in the groupview,but what i do is adding the SurfaceView to the LinearLayout by WindowManager , then when i open the application ,which is covered by the Home, and next takepicture action would be performed, then the application crashed, do you have Done this like that? you can try it,perhaps somewhere is wrong

Comment: @MikeP. I'm so sorry to reply you today, please forgive me, an that time , I give up the issue,so i don't know how to response to you,I have described my problem above. you can see it if you have extra time